# Hyperledger installation issue with docker

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is a first time i am testing hyperkedger bloackchain framework but I am facing some issues.

I am trying to install hyperledger on ubuntu image, everything were fine as per the instructions mentioned in this site https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html . But after calling this command

```
mkdir ~/fabric-tools && cd ~/fabric-tools

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-dev-servers.zip
unzip fabric-dev-servers.zip
```

Following output was came

```
myuser@ubuntu:~/fabric-tools$ ./downloadFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'downloadFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

# Set ARCH
ARCH=`uname -m`
uname -m

# Grab the current directory.
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
 cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd 
 dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 

# Pull and tag the latest Hyperledger Fabric base image.
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.4
/home/myuser/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/downloadFabric.sh: line 13: docker: command not found
```

So I have tried to install the docker manually using and afterward using the same command i get the following error.

```
 sudo ./downloadFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'downloadFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

# Set ARCH
ARCH=`uname -m`
uname -m

# Grab the current directory.
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
 cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd 
 dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 

# Pull and tag the latest Hyperledger Fabric base image.
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.4
Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-peer:i686-1.0.4 not found
```

From here i am unable to understand what is the problem and how i can download the proper docker image. Any tip or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information about your host system, specifically by running `uname -a` ?  My guess right now would be that you are running a 32bit version of Ubuntu

Comment: I have received this information: Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux  and yes its seems 32 bit i guess, what do you suggest ???

Comment: I'm surprised that you were able to install Docker on a 32bit system.  Last time I checked, Docker officially only supports 64bit operating systems and we only build 64bit images for Hyperledger Fabric.  So unfortunately, my only suggestion is to find a 64bit Ubuntu host system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I realized it very late even though I found few tutorial for 32bit dockers for ubuntu but it doesn't work well.

Comment: @Gari Singh Kindly put this comment as an answer so i will select your answer as the last one and closed this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running a 32bit Ubuntu distribution.  Docker officially only supports 64bit operating systems and we only build 64bit images for Hyperledger Fabric. So unfortunately, my only suggestion is to find a 64bit Ubuntu host system.